# convert movie clips into another movie clip

Tags: flash

I have a question regarding to movie clips in Flash, I have made a simple scene which consists of four movie clips (four movie clips in library), I am wondering can I convert these four movie clips into a single movie clip? And how? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can make a single movieClip with four frames, and put each movieclip on a frame. If the link of this movieClip in your library is `Clip`, you can display your four movieClips like that:

```
var c:Clip;
var i:int = 0;

while (i++ < 4) {
    c = new Clip();
    c.x = 100 * i;
    c.gotoAndStop(i);
    this.addChild(c);
}
```